# Topological Sort basic analogy

Tags: graph-algorithm, topological-sort

I was recently going through Topological Sort and DFS from CRLS. They have this entry/exit time concept by which we can classify graph edges into

- tree edge
- forward edge
- back edge
- cross edge

So the question is - does Topological sort using DFS try to remove forward edges from the tree keeping only tree edges to arrive at the sorted result?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if a graph has a back-edge, it is not a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) since it contains a cycle and hence cannot be topologically sorted.

When we're topologically sorting, we are not removing any edge, we're simply providing a linear order so that edges only travel in one direction: from nodes that appear earlier in the order to nodes that appear later. Forward edges are certainly allowed to exist is such an order. What kind of topological order do you believe the following graph exhibits?

[image]